# ContactsPicker not retuning any result

Tags: android, onactivityresult

this is my code

```
//OnClick
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT);

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (reqCode) {
        case (CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT) :
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri contactData = data.getData();
                Cursor c =  getActivity().getContentResolver().query(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    // TODO Whatever you want to do with the selected contact name.
                    Log.d("data",name);
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

I am using this in fragment, and it opens contact list but onActivityResult is never called

Comment: "i dont get any result" -- do you mean that `onActivityResult()` is never called?

Comment: yes...it is not called

Comment: Are you calling `startActivityForResult()` on the fragment, or on the activity? Is your `onActivityResult()` method implemented on the fragment, or on the activity? They need to line up. FWIW, all of [these sample apps](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ConfigChange) do the same operation that you are trying to do, and they have all worked on all devices that I tried them on. Some are plain activities, some use fragments.

Comment: startActivityForResult() and onActivityResult() both are implemented in same fragment

Comment: What you have looks OK then. Check out the two `Fragment*` examples in the directory I listed in my previous comment.

Comment: i am using:  android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

Comment: It is possible that there are variations in behavior due to that, though I am not aware of any.

Answer (score 0):

Because of low reputation i cannon write a comment. Check your manifest.xml for flags like:

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

or

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

as they make it impossible to deliver results. Those flags are used between 
`<activity>` tags

Comment: i have android:noHistory="true" in splashscreen activity

Comment: If this is the activity that contains the fragment, try to remove the flag and check if onActivityResult is called.

Answer (score 0):

i have used this approach in my app:
first add a permission to your manifest.xml file like:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

then call launchContactPicker() when ever you want to show contacts to user:

```
public void launchContactPicker() {
    Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT);
}
```

then on activityResult add this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK)
    {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT:
                Cursor cursor;
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                if(extras != null)
                {
                    Set<String> keys = extras.keySet();
                    for (String key : keys) {
                        extras.get(key);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.v("Auto Respond", "No extras returned from contact.");
                }

                Uri result = data.getData();
                String id = result.getLastPathSegment();
                String[] projection = new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME};
                cursor = getContentResolver().query(result, projection,
                        null, null, null);

                String contactName="";
                String contactNumber="";
                if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())
                {
                    String nameOfselectedContact=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex((ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)));
                    ArrayList<String> numbersOfSelectedContact=new ArrayList<String>();
                    Log.e("contact size", cursor.getCount()+"");
                    for(int i=0;i<cursor.getCount();i++)
                    {
                        numbersOfSelectedContact.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex((ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER))));
                        cursor.moveToNext();
                    }
                    cursor.close();

                }
                    break;
        }
    }

}
```

now you have contact name as a String named as "nameOfselectedContact" and all its numbers as ArrayList named as "numbersOfSelectedContact" , you then can use them as u want (may be show them in a dialog).